# Create a function from another by substituting arguments

Tags: functions, evaluation, hold

Suppose I have a function `f[x, coeff]`

```
coeff[n_] := Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {n + 1}];
f[x_, coeff_] := Sum[coeff[[i + 1]] x^i, {i, 0, Length[coeff] - 1}]
```

and I want to create another function `f1[x]` by substituting the concrete second argument.

**Update:**
At first I tried to define it as a simple function:

```
f1[x_] := f[x, coeff1]
```

But when executing `?f1` I'd like to see the definition of `f1` as a concrete polynomial rather than a definition in terms of another function. In other words I would like `f[x, coeff1]` to be evaluated for `coeff1` but not for `x`.

The closest I could get to that goal was:

```
coeff1 = coeff[1]
f1[x_] := Evaluate[f[Hold[x], coeff1]]
```

This results in f1 containing the `Hold` over `x`:

```
f1[x_] := 1.23788 - 0.790537 Hold[x]
```

Suppose also that a have `x` defined somewhere:

```
x = 1
```

I tried some combinations of `Function`, `ReleaseHold` and `Unevaluated`. For example:

```
f1 = Function[x, Evaluate[f[Hold[x], coeff1]]]

f1[x_] := ReleaseHold[Evaluate[f[Hold[x], coeff1]]]

f1[x_] := Evaluate[f[Unevaluated[x], coeff1]]]
```

... and some others. But I either get a function with `Hold[x]`, or a function which was already evaluated for `x` (a constant in this case). What I want to get is when executing `?f1` I want to see:

```
f1[x_] := 1.23788 - 0.790537 x
```

rather than

```
f1[x_] := 1.23788 - 0.790537 Hold[x]
```

Could anyone please explain how to force the WL's evaluation algorithm to do this?

Comment: Try `Clear[f1]; f1[x_] := f[x, coeff[1]]` for the first part of your problem. For the second part, if $x$ is defined, it will be substituted in: you can't reasonably avoid that. You seem to be trying very hard to work *against* normal practices, which suggests that there is another underlying problem that you are trying to solve in this forcing way. Perhaps you should explain why you need this behavior instead: there might be a better, more natural way to achieve what you ultimately want.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you. I have updated my question.

Comment: "...For the second part, if x is defined, it will be substituted in: you can't reasonably avoid that. ..." My idea was that if it is possible to define a function `g[x_]:=x + 1` without `x` being evaluated, then it is likely possible with my problem too.

Comment: to "recover" a polynomial expression from the function `f1`, the simplest way would be to just evaluate `f1[x]` , where `x` is unassigned.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want is: f1[x_] = f[x, coeff[1]] This will evaluate at once. However if you say: f1[x_] := f[x, coeff[1]] the evaluation is delayed to when you call the function.

Comment: And to evaluate an expression in `x` such as `exp = 0.655591 + 0.23043 x`, you can use replacement rules such as `exp/.{x->7}`

Comment: @Daniel Huber Thank you. Unfortunately `f1[x_] = f[x, coeff[1]]` doesn't work, because `x` is defined and it gets substituted. What I want is `f1[x_] ` to be defined as a polynomial. I want `f[x, coeff[1]]` to be evaluated for `coeff`, but not for `x`

Comment: Can't you choose an undefined variable instead of x? If no, you could try: `Clear[f1]; With[{x = Unique[]}, f1[x, 2] = f[x, coeff[1]]]`

Comment: I can choose another name. I just want to understand how evaluation works in this case.