# Symbol scope in `SetDelayed` and `Evaluate`

Tags: evaluation, symbols

In my previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257676/create-a-function-from-another-by-substituting-arguments) I described a problem, when one of the approaches I tried to use didn't work because of the interaction between `Evaluate[]` in combination with `SetDelayed[]`.

Suppose we have a symbol defined in a global scope:

```
x = 1;
```

And now we defined a function:

```
f[x_] := x + 1
```

In this case Mathematica understands that `x` refers to the function argument and not to the global symbol:

```
?f

(* Definitions: f[x_] := x + 1 *)
```

Now I want to define one function in terms of another:

```
f[x_, a_] := a x
f1[x_] := f[x, 1] + 1
?f1

(* Definitions: f1[x_] := f[x, 1] + 1 *)
```

As expected again `x` here refers to the function argument.

Now I want to simplify the definition of `f1`, so that it looks like:

```
(* Definitions: f1[x_] := 1 + x *)
```

and I use `Evaluate[]`:

```
f1[x_] := Evaluate[f[x, 1] + 1]
```

But instead of `1 + x` I get:

```
(* Definitions: f1[x_] := 2 *)
```

Because when applying `Evaluate[]` to an expression containing `x` Mathematica thinks that I'm referring to a global `x` rather than the function argument.

Why does `Evaluate[]` work like this? Is there any way to override the scope of the `x`?

Comment: is this simply because the RHS of the function `f` is now evaluated immediately, and hence will use the global `x`,  and not when the function `f` is called in order to use its argument `x` instead? In effect, writing `f1[x_] := Evaluate[f[x, 1] + 1]` is as if you have written `f1[x_] = f[x, 1] + 1]` countering the whole reason to use the delayed assignment,.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't think about these things in terms of "scope", as that will lead to confusion. Mathematica does not (usually) use "scope" in the way you may be familiar with from other languages. In particular, `SetDelayed` does not do any scoping at all<sup>*</sup>. All it does is hold off from evaluating the RHS. The symbol `x` you write there *is exactly the same* as the symbol `x` you called "global". The only difference is in when and how `x` is evaluated, but not in the identify of `x`.

But let's talk about how to fix your example. As you know, the problem is that `x` has a value. If `x` had no value, then `f1[x_] := Evaluate[f[x, 1] + 1]` would work as you want it to. One possible solution is to temporarily unset `x`'s value. We do this with `Block`.

```
Block[{x},
 f1[x_] := Evaluate[f[x, 1] + 1]
]

Definition[f1]

(* f1[x_] := 1 + x *)
```

`Block` does [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scope). Essentially, it temporarily removes all definitions from `x`.

Additional reading:

- [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/12)

---

<sup>* To be accurate, Mathematica does do some scoping, and `SetDelayed` does interact with it. This is why we can't use `Module` instead of `Block` in my example. But discussing this here would distract from the main topic.</sup>

Comment: Great! Thank you. That's what I was looking for. I actually tried using `Module` in my tests but obviously it didn't work.